# Do I need to file US tax forms if I'm outside US the whole year but received an award money?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, income-tax-refund

I was previously an international PhD student in the USA on F1 visa, and I graduated in August 2022 (was a resident alien in 2022), and moved to Germany late 2022. Then in May 2023 I received an award money of $5000 from my graduate school due to excellence of my PhD work. But I've never been in USA the whole year of 2023, do I still need to file tax forms for year 2023 reporting this award money? My school didn't withhold any tax for this award, do I need to pay tax for it (if so, how to pay for that?)?

Answer (score 1):

This income is taxable. It is considered FDAP (Fixed/Determinable/Annual/Periodical) income and is taxed at flat 30% (unless a tax treaty provides anything else).

See [the IRS page on FDAP](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/fixed-determinable-annual-periodical-fdap-income):

> Tax at a 30% (or lower treaty) rate applies to FDAP income or gains from U.S. sources, but only if they are not effectively connected with your U.S. trade or business. The 30% (or lower treaty) rate applies to the gross amount of U.S. source fixed or determinable, annual, or periodical gains, profits, or income. Deductions and netting are not allowed against FDAP income.
>
> The following items are examples of FDAP income:
>
> ...
>
> - Scholarships and fellowship grants
> - Other grants, prizes and awards
>
> ...

Since the income is in 2023, after you've left already, you'll probably be filing the non-resident 1040NR form.